# How to pass some variables from renderer to WebView?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webview, electron

Say I am using `<webview>` tags, how can I pass some variables or functions to the webview before the page is loaded?

I know about the `preload` property, but I am already using it to preload a script and the script is static. I want to pass some variable that can change in the renderer process any time